# Would it be correct to use limits in this way for functions with asymptotes?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$$

Would it be appropriate to say these limits?
$$\lim_{x\to-1^+}f(x)=+\infty$$
And for
$$\lim_{x\to-1^-}f(x)=-\infty$$

Comment: Yes. Is there a particular reason that this confuses you?

Comment: Some people insist that a limit must be a (finite) real number.  If that is how your instructors do it, then you should say that this function has no limit as $x\to-1^+$, nor as $x\to-1^-$.

Answer (score 0):

Limits have several (equivalent) definitions. One of them says that in order for an output to be a limit, you must be able to draw an arbitrarily small open interval around the output so that any point close enough to your target input will always end up in that interval. Using this definition, I don't think infinitely large outputs can properly be a limit.

However, knowing that a function increases (or decreases) without bound as the input approaches some value is important to know, so many mathematicians and professors use limit notation as you did to express that idea.